# In Fallout: The Roleplaying Game (2d20 system by Modiphius), is it intended that gun bashing with a missile launcher would have the blast quality?

Tags: weapons, melee-combat, designer-reasons, fallout-the-role-playing-game

I have noticed that gun bash simply states a one-handed gun or a two-handed gun, so there seems no reason you could not gun bash with a big gun (which are all two-handed guns). The part where it gets weird is where it says the qualities for a gun bash are "as weapon". I get that the intention of this is for properties like accurate, inaccurate, and handedness to apply, but for big guns this would also copy properties like gatling and blast. **Is it intended that a missile launcher could therefore be used to do a melee gun bash attacking the entire zone and therefore possibly stunning the entire zone (since gun bash adds the stun damage effect)?** This seems very powerful, as there are no other melee weapons that have blast or any way to target more than one opponent.

I could see maybe allowing some sort of melee attack hitting multiple targets with a big gun simply because its so big and a supermutant swinging it around could hit more than target maybe, but this also seems logically inconsistent. Why does a blast big gun, like a missile launcher, which is blast because its missiles explode with shrapnel, gun bash as blast hitting multiple targets, where a minigun, which is arguable just as long/big as the missile launcher can't do the same type of overhand swing melee blast attack?

Furthermore, the way the blast quality is worded, giving a melee weapon blast would be very absurd because of the way blast is worded "...you do not attack a single opponent. Instead, target a zone you can see...". So rules as written if you are carrying a missile launcher you could gun bash an entire zone of enemies, potentially stunning them, at long range (albeit at difficulty 4, this is hittable with action points and tagged skills and re-rolls from aiming, and even if you miss, you still deal half damage to them).

**Did they really intent for everything to be copied?** I beleive this this was an oversight and that melee gun bashes were only supposed to get the handedness and accuracy qualities of the gun, and not the other qualities like gatling and blast, but I would love confirmation of this.

Comment: Just to confirm: you are NOT asking if this works, but whether or not there is a designer statement on the intent of it working?

Comment: as far as I can tell, by RAW this works (unless I am missing something, in which case by all means point it out), but I am convinced RAI it should not, so getting clarification from the designer would be preferred.

Comment: Just a reminder for answers: This IS a designer-reasons question and needs a reason from a designer to answer it :)

Comment: Why does your disbelief start at that, and not already at the "accurate" quality?

Comment: because the accuracy stuff makes a certain amount of sense. I approached it from the "innacurate" side fo things. Saying that a gun that is poorly balanced for shootign probably also isn't the most balanced melee weapon. This made sense to me, so accurate as an extrapolation of that also makes sense to me. Also, accurate is irrelevant, as you can already spend AP for damage on melee attacks, so that property copying doesn't affect the gun bash at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I have heard back from Modiphius by one of the designers on their errata forum. [The errata forum post](https://forums.modiphius.com/t/faq-and-errata-thread/14660/476) says:

> The only qualities that should be conferred to a gun bash from the
> weapon’s normal ranged profile is Two Handed, and any others that
> represent the weapon’s physical structure (such as Concealed)

This is a satisfactory answer to me and follows my gut reaction of the RAW not being the designer intent.